# Find a function $f(x)$ such that $f\left(n\right)=a_n$ converges but $\lim _{x\to \infty }\:f\left(x\right)$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is there a function $f(x)$ such that $f\left(n\right)=a_n$ converges but $\lim _{x\to \infty }\:f\left(x\right)$ does not exist?

Comment: $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ ?

Comment: How about $\,f(x)=x - \lfloor x \rfloor\,$ a.k.a. the fractional part of $\,x\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on eugenhu’s comment: pick $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$, you can see that for any natural number you receive the constant sequence made by all $0$s, while for any real number the sequence keeps oscillating, hence the limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$ does not exist.